# How to ClearInterval outside of UseEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, clearinterval

Saw a few questions similar to this, but was not able to find an answer.

When the page loads, I want to start running these 2 functions (http requests). However, when there is an error, I want to be able to ClearInterval. However, given that those 2 setIntervals are invoked and declared within useEffect, I'm unable to clear it outside.

```
const [error, setError] = useState("");

// fetchSnapshot function here
// fetchData function here

useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(fetchSnapshot, 5000);
    setInterval(fetchData, 5000);
  }, []);
```

This seems like a scope issue but I'm not sure how to solve this.

I've tried several solutions like

- Declaring a variable globally and then update it within the useEffect. This did not work for me, likely because the setInterval was declared and invoked inside.
- Setting the dependency array as the local error state and then adding an IF statement within the useEffect to trigger the clearInterval, but didn't really work out...

I need the clearInterval to only trigger if my local error state is updated and no longer falsy. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Use ref to store the id and then clear it.

Comment: Store the interval id, and pass that to your 2 functions.  You also really want to clear these intervals on unmount too.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help! Solved it with @Tushar Shahi 's answer, which is a guided version of what you guys were suggesting. Appreciate the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `ref` to store the interval ids. Clear them when your state variable changes.

```
const [error, setError] = useState("");
const snapshotIntervalRef = useRef();
const dataIntervalRef = useRef();

// fetchSnapshot function here
// fetchData function here

useEffect(() => {
   snapshotIntervalRef.current = setInterval(fetchSnapshot, 5000);
      dataIntervalRef.current = setInterval(fetchData, 5000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(snapshotIntervalRef.current);
      clearInterval(dataIntervalRef.current);
   };

}, []);


useEffect(() => {
if(error) {
      clearInterval(snapshotIntervalRef.current);
      clearInterval(dataIntervalRef.current);
}

},[error]);
```

I have added a cleanup function in first `useEffect`. That is to avoid memory leaks, but the relevant solution is in the second useEffect

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved the problem. I assume the cleanup function is the return part of the useEffect, which is also the unmounting mentioned by keith in the reply comments to my question. Learned about useRef and the importance of cleanup function here, appreciate you all for the quick replies.

Comment: this bring us to: `Type 'Timeout' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.ts(2322)`